# Generalizing custom buttons in React: custom text and background-image

Tags: reactjs, web-component

I am trying to create a group of four buttons. The buttons are almost identical save the background-image and the text on the button. I could create a component for each button, but am trying to implement a more generalized approach. My native language is Java, I keep trying to think of components as objects.

I tried

**ImgBtn.js**
(This would act like the constructor)

```
import './App.css';
function ImgBtn(customImg, btnTxt) {
    return (
     <>
      <button style = {{backgroundImage : customImg}}>'btnTxt'</button>
     </>   
      );
  }

  export default ImgBtn;
```

**App.js **
(Where I would invoke the four instances of ImgBtn, just focusing on one for now)

```
import ImgBtn from './ImgBtn';
import practRange from "./btn_img/p-range.png";


function App() {
render(
    <div>
   { <ImgBtn(customImg: practRange, btnTxt: sample)/>;}
   </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

**App.css **
(The general styling for the buttons)

```
 body {
  background-color: aqua;
}
button {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
img {
  margin-top: none;
  padding-top: none;

}
```

I was hoping ImgBtn would act as a "constructor" that I could use to invoke the four different buttons, but I got an error. I am pretty sure it all relates to my confusion around how parameters (props?) work in React.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The props comes as an object in the components. So you have to destructurine it in your component like this:

```
function ImgBtn({customImg, btnTxt}) {
    return (
     <>
      <button style = {{backgroundImage : customImg}}>{btnTxt}</button>
     </>   
      );
  }
```

And in your App.tsx, you pass the props directly in the component like this:

```
function App() {
render(
    <div>
     <ImgBtn customImg={practRange} btnTxt={'sample'})/>
   </div>
);
}
```

To know more details about how the props works in React, take a look at the official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Hope this answer helped you! :)

Comment: Wow this was really helpful, thank you. The image doesn't show up on the button unless I include these   
 'background-image: url("btn_img/p-range.png");'
    'background-size: contain;'
    'background-repeat: no-repeat;'
 in the App.css button selector. I tried it inline but I keep getting errors. Is it possible inline?

Comment: You're welcome, i'm here to help :). Yes, this link https://www.javatpoint.com/inline-style-in-react shows you exactly how you can do "inline styling".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it to work using the resource you linked and some concatenation. It looked like this in the end 
function ImgBtn({customImg, btnTxt}) {
    return (
     <div>
      <button style = {
        {backgroundImage : "url(" + customImg + ')'
        }}>
            {btnTxt}</button>
     </div>   
      );
  }

Answer (score 1):

hm I think your syntax is causing errors, it's not quite React :). for instance, the  component comes with these props (customImg, btnText), you will need to pass them when declaring the component in App.js.

```
function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ImgBtn customImg={practRange} btnText="test" />
        </div>
      );
}
```

perhaps you'd be interested in reading up on React basics.

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html